# Lines not being drawn in Octave

Tags: octave

I am instructed to draw a circle with the points that are transformed by a matrix. I cannot seem to get a line to draw between all the points

```
c = cos(pi/8)
s = sin(pi/8)
A = [c -s; s c]
xy = [1;0]
axis('square')
for i = 1:17
  xy = A * xy;
  plot(xy(1, :), xy(2,:), 'r', 'linewidth', 2);
  hold on
endfor
```

When I run the code I get this

[image: Result of running the code]

How would I get the lines to be drawn between all the points?

Thanks

Comment: It draws lines for you?

Comment: I get no lines in Octave 3.8.2.

Comment: Sorry @beaker that was intended for someone else they have since deleted the comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate all of the points before you plot. If you plot only one point at a time, it has nowhere to connect a line to.

```
c = cos(pi/8)
s = sin(pi/8)
A = [c -s; s c]
xy = zeros(2,17);   %// preallocate the matrix
xy(:,1) = [1;0]
for i = 2:17
  xy(:,i) = A * xy(:,i-1);
endfor

plot(xy(1, :), xy(2,:), 'r', 'linewidth', 2);
axis('square')   %// goes *after* the plot (thanks @Andy)
```

[image: Plot created by script]

Comment: Sorry for not posting the plot itself. I'm having trouble with saving the figure for some reason.

Comment: Btw, you have to place the "axis('square')" after the plot command.

Comment: @Andy Yep, my bad.